# EF migration is updating existing rows with null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have both a User and Password models which resemble the below. The Password model is new and so is the Password property on the User model.

```
public class Password {
    public int PasswordID { get; set; }
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Password Password { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to update my EF migration which will take the existing users and update them accordingly with the new Password foreign key whilst also creating the corresponding row in the Password table. My configuration.cs looks something like this...

```
var Users = new List<User> {
    new User() { Name = "Donald", Surname = "Duck", Password = new Password() { HashedPassword = "somehashedstring", LastUpdated = DateTime.Now }},
   ...
}

Users.ForEach(a => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(b => new { b.Name, b.Surname }, a));
context.SaveChanges();
```

EDIT: Obviously the Name and Surname combination shouldn't define a row as unique but for the time being it will do. This isn't a production application.

But I'm finding that after running `update-database` my final Users table in SQL contains NULL in the Password_PasswordID column and the Password table is empty. I feel that I've followed the documentation and guides but obviously I must be going wrong somewhere. If you require any extra info please ask!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put this as a comment but my reputation is low so here is what I hope helps with your code.
I recently done s.th similar to your task and was successful.

Visually the User and Password models look correct to me. So to debug this I suggest:

**First** - Check the foreign key is generated as expected by EF migration and EF update database commands. I use SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual studio to check this.
Check the image of DepartmentId in this post
http://anurajchandrandotnet.blogspot.com/2014/11/customizing-table-column-and-foreign.html

**Second** - This is my DatabaseSeeder class for your case but I have not compiled it. If this works for you, then you can try to make it shorter.

```
public static class DatabaseSeeder
    {
        public static void SeedData(AppDbContext context)
        {
            if (context.User.Any(m => m.FooId == "foo"))
            {
                // or any checks to avoid overwriting your data - Optional
                return;
            }

            var userA = new User
            {
                Name = "Donald",
                Surname = "Duck",
                Password = new Password
                {
                    HashedPassword = "somehashedstring",
                    LastUpdated = DateTime.Now
                }
            };

            var userB = new User
            {
                Name = "DonaldB",
                Surname = "DuckB",
                Password = new Password
                {
                    HashedPassword = "somehashedstring",
                    LastUpdated = DateTime.Now
                }
            };

            var users = new List<User>
            {
                userA,
                userB
            };

            context.Partners.AddRange(users);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I can confirm that the migration is creating the column. I've found that if the migration can insert the rows then the Password table is populated as expected and the foriegn keys are also added in the Users table. The problem occurs when the migration updates the rows in the Users table instead. Perhpas EF will not create the row in the password table when updating, hence the NULL keys. I'm surprised if this is the case. Perhaps I need to rethink my seeding strategy.